# Go parse string to time

Tags: go

I've got the following string:

```
Sun, 03 Jan 2016 10:00:07 CET
```

Id like to parse it into time, but cannot seem to figure out how to write the format.

This is what I've got so far:

```
layout := "Mon, 01 Jan 03:04:05"
t, _ := time.Parse(layout, "Sun, 03 Jan 2016 10:00:07 CET")
fmt.Println(t)
```

Output I get is:

```
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Comment: `time.Parse()` returns an error. Print that and you'll know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: You're silently ignoring the error this is returned as second return value of `time.Parse`. I'd suggest handling the error appropriately, instead.

Secondly, let's have a look at the documentation of [`time.Parse`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse):

> `Parse` parses a formatted string and returns the time value it represents. **The layout defines the format by showing how the reference time, defined to be `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006` would be interpreted if it were the value**; it serves as an example of the input format. The same interpretation will then be made to the input string.

The `time.Parse` function expects its `layout` parameter to represent a fixed example date. So, in order to parse the date `Sun, 03 Jan 2016 10:00:07 CET`, the appropriate example layout string should be `Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST`:

```
layout := "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST"
t, err := time.Parse(layout, "Sun, 03 Jan 2016 10:00:07 CET")
if err != nil {
    // handle the error somehow!
}

fmt.Println(t)
```